# how to use loader and html content via ajax using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

here's my code

```
   $('#loader').hide()
   .ajaxStart(function(){
     $(this).show();
   })
   .ajaxStop(function(){
     $(this).hide();
   });


   $('form#jobsearch').submit(function(){
      $("div.job-search-content").hide();
      $("div#pagination").hide();

       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "classes/ajax.simplesearch.php",
          data: $('form#jobsearch').serialize(),
          success: function(data){
          // I DONT" REALLY KNOW WHAT TO DO IN THIS PART 
            $(data).insertAfter('#job-search-headings').html();
              //$("div.job-search-content").show();
          }
       });
        return false;
   });
});
```

if I hide the job-search-content div, it will show the loader
but the problem is, how will I add the retrieved database content under the 
'#job-search-headings' div ? ....I checked in firebug..I was able to retrieve the correct data..but I wasn't able to display it at front-end  :(

Answer (score 2):

if you want to display the ajax results on the div "job-search-content"

```
$("div.job-search-content").html(data).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

data is the responce from the page you're posting to so if the page returns something like `<div>some content</div>`
change

```
$(data).insertAfter('#job-search-headings').html();
```

to

```
$('#job-search-headings').after(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('#job-search-headings').after(data);
```

Comment: Should be working, you might have a DIV on `.hide()` or `display: none` which contains the data.

Comment: how to make the loader stay a bit longer?..i mean, it's too fast..like, i wanna show it to the end user that it is currently loading a data even if it's only trying to fetch only 1 data.. i just want the loader to be shown for about 5 seconds or less ?